# Kmeans Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I would like to perform KMeans using the Spark ML. Input is a libsvm dataset:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
  // Start time
  //val intial_Data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv("C://sample_lda_data.txt")
  val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("C:\\spark\\data\\mllib\\sample_kmeans_data.txt")
  // Trains a k-means model.
  val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L)
  val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)

  // Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors.
  val WSSSE = model.computeCost(dataset)
  println(s"Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = $WSSSE")

  // Shows the result.
  println("Cluster Centers: ")
  model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

So i would like to use a csv file and apply KMeans by the Spark ML. 
I did this:

```
 val intial_Data=spark.read.option("header",true).csv("C://sample_lda_data.txt")
        val arrayCol= array(inputData.columns.drop(1).map(col).map(_.cast(DoubleType)): _*)
                    import spark.implicits._
                    // select array column and first column, and map into LabeledPoints
                    val result = inputData.select(col("col1").cast(DoubleType), arrayCol).map(r => LabeledPoint(r.getAs[Double](0),Vectors.dense(r.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](1).toArray)))
                    // Trains a k-means model
                    val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2)
        val model = kmeans.fit(result)
          // Evaluate clustering by computing Within Set Sum of Squared Errors.
      val WSSSE = model.computeCost(dataset)
      println(s"Within Set Sum of Squared Errors = $WSSSE")

      // Shows the result.
      println("Cluster Centers: ")
      model.clusterCenters.foreach(println)
```

I tried to turn csv file into a `Dataset[LabledPoint]`.

Is my transformation correct?

Comment: With the new API, you don't need to transform your csv into a `DataSet[LabeledPoint]` you just need one column with all your features which you can obtain through `VectorAssembler`.
I wrote an example [here](https://github.com/BenFradet/spark-ml/blob/master/chapter7/src/main/scala/io/github/benfradet/spark/ml/in/action/GitHubKMeans.scala).

Comment: @BenFradet hi friend , i just noticed your message , thnx a lot friend ,i got another question , and if will to get a column name label ? what shoud i do ?

Comment: what do you mean by: "if will to get a column name label"?

Answer (score 0):

In spark 2 instead of MLlib , we are using ML package. Which workon dataset and ML flows work in pipeline model. What u need to do is U have to make a dataset and make two columns feature,label. feature is the a vector of features u need to feed into the algo. The other column label is the target column. To make feature column u just need to use vector assembler to assemble all the features u want to use. If you have a target colunm then rename it as label. after fitting this dataset into algo u will get your model.